# Rewriting sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have where clause in my rails app that looks like this:

```
Report.where("lower(coalesce(#{organization_tables_with_name.join(',')})) LIKE lower(?)","%#{organization_name}%")
```

it works as expected but this code is vulnerable to sql injection. I rewrite this to something like that:

```
Report.where("lower(coalesce(?)) LIKE lower(?)", organization_tables_with_name,"%#{organization_name}%")
```

but this not works. The problem is that after sending to coalesce paremeter it makes quotes around it:

```
WHERE(lower(coalesce('k12_seas.name,k12_leas.name,k12_schools.name,k12_sections.name'))
```

but it should be:

```
WHERE (lower(coalesce(k12_seas.name,k12_leas.name,k12_schools.name,k12_sections.name))
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It returns:
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "lower"
LINE 1: ...,'k12_schools.name','k12_sections.name')) OR LIKE lower('%MS...

Comment: Please paste organization_tables_with_name and organization_name values

Comment: organization_tables_with_name = ["k12_seas.name", "k12_leas.name", "k12_schools.name", "k12_sections.name"]

orgnization_name = 'Some string'

Comment: The sql  that this generate is the same like my:

WHERE (lower(coalesce('k12_seas.name,k12_leas.name,k12_schools.name,k12_sections.name'))

the problem is with this qoutes...

Comment: Im out of ideas how to solve this problem...

Comment: What type returns ```organization_tables_with_name```? Array?
I tried calc your expression, and got correct result
```organization_tables_with_name``` defined manually as array (took definition from your comment)

Comment: Yes it returns array:

 
organization_tables_with_name = ["k12_seas.name", "k12_leas.name", "k12_schools.name", "k12_sections.name"]

Comment: check ```organization_tables_with_name.class.name``` or ```organization_tables_with_name.is_a? Array```

Comment: Very strange... Then there is only manual string joining via ```inject``` or ```each``` methods

Comment: Stop, what returns ```organization_tables_with_name.join(',')``` expression without ```Report.where```? Has it quotes?

Comment: It returns:
"k12_seas.name,k12_leas.name,k12_schools.name,k12_sections.name"

Comment: No quotes, so problem is in Report.where.
Is it ActiveRecord model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84038/discussion-between-mateusz-urbanski-and-general-failure).

Comment: I can't open http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ - our admin use white list at router
Let's talk here or wait when i come home

Comment: I will rewrite those queries because this coalesce hacks are shitty.

Comment: I think that reason is in ```Report``` model or your database adapter gem, not coalesce or other sql words